# Visualize 2D numpy array in colormap

Tags: python, numpy, colors

How can I change the text and background color of the numpy array below, based on its numbers? Running on Colab.

```
[[ 0.   0.  -1. ]
 [ 0.5  0.5  0. ]
 [ 0.   0.  -1. ]
 [ 0.   0.5  0. ]
 [ 0.5  0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   1.   0. ]]
```

I would like to have something like this, but with the numbers showing when it's not zero

[image: desired output]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `seaborn.heatmap`(https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

a = np.random.choice([np.nan,.5,1], 27).reshape(9,3)

a

Out[1]: array([[nan, 1. , nan],
               [1. , 1. , 1. ],
               [0.5, nan, 1. ],
               [0.5, 1. , 1. ],
               [0.5, nan, 0.5],
               [1. , 1. , nan],
               [nan, nan, 1. ],
               [1. , 1. , nan],
               [nan, 1. , 0.5]])
```

```
sns.heatmap(a, annot=True)
```

[image]